# Shifting a cell based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to look in column A see if the word outside exists. If it does NOT, then move to column J and if that is cell is NOT blank then shift the cell and subsequently shift all cells in that row to the left. Below is what I have, but is not working. What is wrong with my code?

```
Sub CleanReportStep5a()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("copied") 
Dim i As Long
      For i = 19 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Range("A" & i) <> "Outside" Then
            If ws.Range("J" & i) <> " " Then
                ws.Range("J" & i).Delete Shift:=xlShiftleft
               End If
      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I totally misread that as "the world outside exists", and thought it was some sort of metaphysical question!  I think your idea of a blank cell being a single space is the issue.  Try `""` instead?

Comment: Try this edit...Into second if write "" no " " because you compere whit white space...

Comment: Thanks @ Richard Hansell for your suggestion. I tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `IsEmpty(ws.Range("J" & i)) = False`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`SpecialCells()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) method of `Range` object and loop through column J not empty cells from row 19 downards (see comments for explanations):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CleanReportStep5a()
    Dim rngToScan As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("copied") 'reference wante sheet
        On Error Resume Next ' prevent any error possibly raised from subsequent statement from stoppoing the code
        Set rngToScan = Intersect(.Range("J:J").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), .Rows("19:" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row)) ' set the range to scan to referenced sheet column J not empty cells from row 19 down to last not empty one
        On Error GoTo 0 ' get default error handling back
    End With

    If rngToScan Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' if no range to be scanned then exit sub

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rngToScan ' loop through range to scan
        If cell.Offset(, -9).Value2 <> "Outside" Then cell.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft ' if value in column A and current cell row is not "Outside" then delete current cell
    Next
End Sub
```